# Get right bitrate with FFmpeg in x264 MP4

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to get the requested bitrate when converting to the libx264 vcodec? It seems ffmpeg doesn't consider the `-b` parameter. I also tried `-minrate`, `-maxrate`, `-bufsize`, `-bt`, but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this guide for ffmpeg x264 conversion](http://rob.opendot.cl/index.php/useful-stuff/ffmpeg-x264-encoding-guide/), you will see that he uses both `-b` and `-bt` together to specify the bitrate. I haven't tried this myself, so I don't know if it woks.